# Adding edges to bars in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

I have been following the example provided in:
https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

My problem is that I want to add edges to the bars. But when I set the

linewidth=1, edgecolor='black'

parameters, the edges are only applied to the first pair of bars, leaving the remaining pairs unchanged.

```
"""
========
Barchart
========

A bar plot with errorbars and height labels on individual bars
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r', yerr=men_std,linewidth=1, edgecolor='black')

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y', yerr=women_std, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

[image: The image I obtain, with edges only for the first pair of bars and the legend.]

Thanks for your help.

David.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using `matplotlib.__version__=='2.2.2'`

Comment: I was using version 2.1.0. After upgrading to 2.2.2 the problem was solved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above (from Diziet Asahi on May 25, 2018 at 20:24) this problem is automatically solved by using a more recent version of matplotlib (probably version 2.2.2 and above).